# Finding an orthonormal basis from an existing one in a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Suppose we are given a separable Hilbert space $H$ with countable orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Suppose we are given an orthonormal set $\{f_n\}$ such that $\sum\|e_n-f_n\| < 1$. How do we prove that $\{f_n\}$ is in fact an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Maybe look at a transformation that maps $e_n\to f_n$ and prove that it is invertible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space is an orthonormal basis if and only if it is *complete*, that is $x\perp f_n$ for all $n$ if and only if $x=0$.

So, suppose that $x\perp f_n$ for all $n$ but $x\neq 0$.  Then,

$$
\vert \langle x,e_n\rangle\vert = \vert \langle x,e_n-f_n+f_n\rangle\vert \leq \vert \langle x,e_n-f_n\rangle\vert+\vert \langle x,f_n\rangle\vert=\vert\langle x,e_n-f_n\rangle\vert
$$ where the last equality follows since $\langle x,f_n\rangle = 0$ for all $n$ by assumption.  Squaring both sides and using CSB inequality, we obtain

$$
\vert \langle x,e_n\rangle\vert^2\leq \vert\langle x,e_n-f_n\rangle\vert^2\leq \|x\|^2\|e_n-f_n\|^2
$$  Summing both sides, we obtain

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert \langle x,e_n\rangle\vert^2\leq \|x\|^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|e_n-f_n\|^2
$$  Now, your assumption that $\sum\|e_n-f_n\|<1$  implies that the sum of the *squares*  is also strictly less than one.  Thus if $x\perp f_n$ for all $n$, we have shown that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert\langle x,e_n\rangle\vert^2 < \|x\|^2,
$$which is a contradiction of the Pythagorean theorem/Parseval's identity.  Thus $x=0$, and $\{f_n\}$ is complete.

Comment: Brilliant! $\ $

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!